# By what criteria does Mathematica generate the list of group elements in `GroupElements[group]`?

Tags: functions, group-theory

I ask because aside from always giving the identity element first, I have found a "pattern" associated with the list given by `GroupElements[group]`. This "pattern" is not preserved if I use `Sort[GroupElements[group]]` which does rearrange the list.

Comment: There are some hints in the documentation. Under `Scope`, it says "The first permutation is always the identity. Then we have permutations moving the last points of the support:" and then some code that explains what it means.  I haven't looked very carefully into that yet though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in a comment, permutations given by GroupElements are ordered according to how the points of the support (i.e. the elements of PermutationSupport[group]) are moved.

Effectively this means that the permutation-list forms of the permutations are sorted lexicographically. For example, for a given group, say

```
group = PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{3, 5}}], Cycles[{{1, 2, 3}}]}]
```

compute:

```
n = PermutationMax[group];
perms = PermutationList[#, n] & /@ GroupElements[group]
```

Then OrderedQ[perms] should always return True.